# Logout issue regarding access token expiry in React native App

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0

I am working on a react native app that has a PHP backend. I am getting an issue with [OAuth2](https://oauth.net/2/). Following is the scenario.

1. User enters the login screen, he will get an access token. Which is
   saving in async storage.
2. Whenever the user is successfully identified, the auth service provider issues an  `access_token` and `refresh_token`
3. The app uses the access token to fetch more user information.
4. access token is expired. Then I got into the app and closed sooner(which will send a request for a new access token but upon closing the app, the response won't be stored in the device, rather it will update the backend refresh token). This causes refresh token mismatch and lead to app log out.
5. When I'm trying to open the app I get thrown out and I need to log in again due to the mismatch of refresh token at backend and async storage.

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: I don't quite follow what happens in step 4. If you have the refresh token, what you can do, is to catch a 401 / 403 response from the server, which should indicate that the token is expired. Then use the refresh token to get a new access token and perform the action again. I think there should not be a need to close the app and open again.

Comment: Agree with @Michal Trojanowski. What you need is an interceptor to catch 401 and then try to fetch new token using refresh token and then re-request the original URL or logout incase refresh token is expired as well. Not sure how you've channelled your request but I use axios which comes with interceptor prebuilt.

Comment: hi @MichalTrojanowski
thanks for replying. Could you please go through the 4th point now?

Comment: But is the app closed? If it's not closed then everything works fine, right?

Comment: yes, it works well if the app  won't closed asap

Comment: This is a problem we faced too. To make things a little more clear, the issue happens when app is closed before the response reach the client in point 4. Server will have new key and client have old key. This makes the app to log out which confuses user.